# Weird formatted date from database datetime

Tags: php, mysql, momentjs

I'm current fetching data from database via ajax with result in json. in that result there was a datetime value from database with this format, e.g. `2013-09-06 07:28:52`

and when I'm using the momentjs with this code:

```
var waktu = moment(response.waktu, 'HH mm ss');
```

the result is:

```
-62167171952000
```

whats wrong and how to return it correctly, just for `HH:mm:ss` ?

thank you.

Comment: [Check docs for formating](http://momentjs.com/docs/).

Comment: thanks for reminding me, it's my wrong @SheikhHeera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, my wrong.

I'm missed understanding the docs. Currently, I'm using [String + Format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) like so:

```
var waktu = moment(response.waktu, 'HH mm ss');
```

then I re-read the [Display format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) section, and tried the following code:

```
var waktu = moment(response.waktu).format('HH : mm : ss');
```

So, to format the datetime given, we have to use the `format()` function, and could not directly used the String + Format, since format here is the format for the given datetime.

Thank you for all of the answer, I really appreciated that. The case is now resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var waktu = moment(response.waktu, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
```

The format string has to match the input string format.

Comment: when I changed to that, the result is `1378427332000`

Comment: That looks about right to me. It's the number of milliseconds since 1/1/1970 00:00:00.

Comment: yes, its my mistake to misunderstanding the `format()` function, its now solved, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to format the date. Doing it in PHP is easy with the value from the database

```
$date = date('h:m:s', strtotime($row['date']));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function in PHP

```
$var = '2013-09-06 07:28:52';
$format='h:m:s';
echo formatDate($var,$format);

/**
* @param datetime $date11 date from db
* @param string $format See Date Parameters in Online Documentation
* @link http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#refsect1-function.date-parameters
* @return string Format Date
*/
function formatDate($date11, $format) {
    $date1 = new DateTime($date11);
    $date = $date1->format($format); //eg: 'm/d/Y' return 07/31/2012
    return $date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative:

```
$timestamp = strtotime('2013-09-06 07:28:52');
echo date("h:m:s", $timestamp); //outputs 07:09:52
```

Comment: the output from PHP is just like the same, but when I passed it to moment() with `HH:mm:ss` format, it gave me `1378427332000`

Comment: then echo the recieved timestamp like `echo date("h:m:s", '1378427332000');`

Comment: correct me if im wrong, but that timestamp you generated looks like a plain 10-digit timestamp with 3 extra 0's added